# Fourier coefficients of an even function

Tags: integration

For an even function $$X_{k}=X_{-k}.$$

$$X_{k}=\frac{1}{T_{0}}\int_{-\frac{T_{0}}{2}}^{\frac{T_{0}}{2}}x(t)e^{-j2\pi\\k\\f_{0}\\t}dt$$

$$X_{-k}=\frac{1}{T_{0}}\int_{-\frac{T_{0}}{2}}^{\frac{T_{0}}{2}}x(t)e^{j2\pi\\k\\f_{0}\\t}dt$$

By doing the change of variable $\alpha =-t$

$$X_{k}=-\frac{1}{T_{0}}\int_{\frac{T_{0}}{2}}^{-\frac{T_{0}}{2}}x(-\alpha)e^{-j2\pi\\kf_{0}\alpha}d\alpha=\frac{1}{T_{0}}\int_{-\frac{T_{0}}{2}}^{\frac{T_{0}}{2}}x(\alpha)e^{-j2\pi\\kf_{0}\alpha}d\alpha=X_{k}$$

I don't understand the change of signs and integration limits in the last part.

In the left side all the t are replaced by $-\alpha$. But why the inversion of the integration limits? Then in the right side the function argument $\alpha$ has the sign changed and the integration limits are inverted, which make sense but why also the whole integral has its sign changed?

Is this valid only for even functions?

Comment: First, please correct your line. There is one minus too much in both integrals and one minus too less in the last expression.

Comment: I double checked from the book, and this matches what's on the book.

Comment: After your editing, it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

When you do the substition
$\alpha = -t$

$d\alpha = -dt$ This flips the sign

$\alpha (\frac{T_0}{2}) = -\frac{T_0}{2}$

$\alpha (-\frac{T_0}{2}) = \frac{T_0}{2}$

This flips the order of integration.  And this would be the case regardless of whether x is even, odd or neither.

But since $x(t)$ is even $x(t) = x(\alpha)$

And $X_{k}$ is even.